# Find missing values in array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array counting multiple values like D0001, D0002, D0003, ...
But sometimes a value is missing, in this case these should be the new ID. If there is no value missing then take the next one in line.
This is the code I used to retrieve an array.

example => array = array("D0001","D0002","D0003","DOOO5");

```
# function finding missing values?
function missing_values($list)
$range = 0;
foreach ($list as $l){
    $nr = $range+1
    if ($l != $nr){
       $id = $nr;
    }
}


$numbers = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "--------------------------------" . "<br/>"; 
    echo "ID " . " --> " . $id ."<br/>"; 
    $id = substr($id,1);
    echo "ID " . " --> " . $id ."<br/>"; 
    $id = ltrim($id, '0');
    echo "ID " . " --> " . $id ."<br/>"; 
    $list[] = $id; 
}
print_r($list);

# Find missing values 
 $array = missing_values($list);

if(empty($array)){
  $max = max($list);
  $id = $max+1;  
}else{
      $keys = array_keys($array);
      $id = $array[$keys[0]];
}
```

Could someone tell me how I can't find the missing values in array? Or are the more easy ways to do this?

Comment: Please add your demo array and expected output

Comment: Pro tip: Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: I recommend on checking the max val in `$list` and compare it with `count(list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Determine the first free id
function get_first_free_id($id_list){
    // construct a new array
    $new_array = range($id_list[0],max($id_list));                                                    
    // use array_diff to find the missing elements 
    $mis_array = array_diff($new_array, $id_list);
    $keys = array_keys($mis_array);
    if(empty($keys)){
        $highest = max($id_array);
        $id = $highest+1;
    }else{
        $id = $mis_array[$keys[0]];
    }
    return $id;

}
```

Comment: Nice answer! (+1) - I would divided the code function returning array of all missing value and outer code who find the first key. Also add notice that you assume the list is sorted (as you taking the first element and not the minimum - or take `min` instead of `[0`]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the bellow logic

```
$myArray = array("D0001","D0002","D0003","D0005", "D0009", "D0019", "D0020", "D0030");

$first = reset($myArray);
$last = end($myArray);

for ($i=$first;  $i<=$last; $i++) {
 $index = array_search($i, $myArray);
  if(!is_numeric($index)) {
      echo "missing " .$i;
      echo "<br>";
  }
 }
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25daa236e6f02a0566dfe0ea06124776dbf20da0